# Hi, I'm looking for how to send a message to all servers and to a specific channel, can you help me?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm looking for how to send a message to all servers and to a specific channel, can you help me?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What do you mean by a "certain channel"? A channel with a certain name?

Comment: I want the message to be sent to all servers and to a channel that has the name 'find-mdt' and if there is no 'find-mdt' channel: return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Looping through all the guilds.
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
    // Getting the channels of the guild.
    const channels = guild.channels.cache.map(channel => channel.name);

    // Checking if the guild has a channel named "find-mdt".
    if (!channels.includes("find-mdt")) {console.log(`Channel not found on ${guild.name}.`); return false;};

    // Sending the message to the channel "find-mdt", if available.
    guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == "find-mdt").send("My Message").then(() => {console.log(`Message sent to ${guild.name}`);}).catch(e => console.log(e));
});
```